# function polymorphisms depending on debug level

Tags: c, debugging, logging, polymorphism

I would like to change below code:

```
#ifdef CONSOLE_VERBOSE_DEBUG
    printf("this debug error message is printed to the console");
#elseif FILE_VERBOSE_DEBUG
    FILE *log = fopen(...);
    ...
    fprintf();
    fclose();
#else 
    ((void) 0) // no debugging
```

into something like

```
callThePropperDebugFct("message");
```

and point this one call to functions declared in the properly included header files depending on which DEBUG level is defined

I know it has to do with c polymorphisms and function pointers, but I can not wrap my head around how to do this

Comment: Define a log-function taking the wanted arguments (possibly printf-style varargs), and have the conditional compilation part inside that function? Don't try to overcomplicate things. :)

Comment: Also note that the `#else` part isn't really needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: ... but if being around needs to be "closed" by a final `#endif`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Define functions to log your message in some `log.c` file
2. Define your `callThePropperDebugFct` macro to call the right function

#### log.c

```
void log_to_console(const char message)
{
    printf("%s", message);   
}

void log_to_file(const char *name, const char *message)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(name, "a");
    if (!f) return;

    fprintf(f, message);    

    fclose(f);
}
```

#### log.h

```
void log_to_console(const char message);
void log_to_file(const char *name, const char *message);

#ifdef CONSOLE_VERBOSE_DEBUG
#define callThePropperDebugFct(message) log_to_console(message); 
#elseif FILE_VERBOSE_DEBUG
#define callThePropperDebugFct(message) log_to_file(LOG_FILE, message)
#else
#define callThePropperDebugFct(message)
#endif
```

---

But you can go further with some variadic macros and variable numbers of arguments functions:

#### log.c

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void log_to_console(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    //vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof buffe, fmt, args);
    vprintf(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

void log_to_file(const char *name, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(name, "a");
    if (!f) return;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(f, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);

    fclose(f);
}
```

#### log.h

```
void log_to_console(const char *fmt, ...);
void log_to_file(const char *name, const char *fmt, ...);

#ifdef CONSOLE_VERBOSE_DEBUG
#define callThePropperDebugFct(...) log_to_console("s", __VA_ARGS__)
#elseif FILE_VERBOSE_DEBUG
#define callThePropperDebugFct(...) log_to_file(LOG_FILE, "%s", __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define callThePropperDebugFct(...)
#endif
```

Comment: I like this use of variadic macro arguments because it eliminates the call of the debug function completely (including possibly complex evaluation/calculation of parameters to put in the debug message) when debugging is turned off. Nice!

Comment: Why the `do..while`? The expansion would already expand to a single function call/statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
#if DEBUG_LEVEL 
#ifndef LOG_OUTPUT
#define LOG_OUTPUT stdio 
#endif
log_function(DEBUG_LEVEL, LOG_OUTPUT, const char *fmt, ...);
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define ATTR __attribute__((format (printf, 3, 4)));
#else
/* ..  */
#endif

void ATTR log_function(int DEBUG_LEVEL, FILE *LOG_OUTPUT, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    /* some code */

    vfprintf(LOG_OUTPUT, fmt, args);    
}
```